# How to add connect-multiparty in routes path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I want to use `connect-multiparty` in my routes . I found only something like below ...

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, resp) {
  console.log(req.body, req.files);
  // don't forget to delete all req.files when done
});
```

But my routes structure is like below ...

```
app.route('/tasks')
    .get(todoList.list_all_tasks)
    .post(todoList.create_a_task);
```

So I tried like this `.post(todoList.create_a_task, multipartMiddleware)` but it got empty in `req.body` . How can I pass correctly `connect-multiparty` in my route for *multipart bodies* request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want mount a middleware for all requests using this pattern; then you should use:

```
app.route('/tasks')
    .all(multipartMiddleware)
    .get(todoList.list_all_tasks)
    .post(todoList.create_a_task);
```

And if you want just mount it to handle post requests then the following should work:

```
app.route('/tasks')
    .get(todoList.list_all_tasks)
    .post(multipartMiddleware, todoList.create_a_task);
```

See: [app.route()](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#app-route)

Also [express.Router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) is a much more modular way for handling routes.